# Limiting the Instances on point to +z (the topside of the model)

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, instances

[image: Node Setup and Modifier Stack]

I am using a series of modifiers and the solidify creates instances on both sides of the model when I only want to limit it to 'top side'

Comment: normal - separate xy**Z** - greater than: `0` (or maybe `0.1` to also avoid spawning on almost vertical faces that are slightly tilted up) - use that as selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your issue, so excuse me if so.  However, I believe the best route to take would be to use the extrude mesh node within geometry nodes instead of a seperate modifier.  The direction can be determined with the normal of the faces to give a similar effect to the solidify modifier.  The extrude mesh node will give a selection output for the top and sides, which you can use to drive the selection of your instance on points node.

Comment: Hi Ian, that worked perfectly - thank you! The only issue I have with it is that the 'underside' is now not solid.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/aqvzoav8oktt3lh71sky2/Nodes-1.jpg?rlkey=n6b9o68wy109qgz0ydjxi0g9s&dl=0

Comment: Yes, that is an easy fix I should have mentioned in my first comment.  All you need to do is take the original geometry before the extrusion, and plug that into a "Join Geometry" node along with the extruded output.  Then from the "Join Geometry" node you can use "Merge By Distance" to make the object solid again.